# Exponential estimation for a length of recurrent monotone sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

> Let  sequence be $$a_{0}=x\in (0,1),a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a^3_{n-1},n=1,2,\cdots$$
>   and define 
>   $$N(x)=\min{\{n|a_{n}>1\}}$$
>
> Assume that there exist constants $A,B > 0$,and constant $C$
>    such that
>   $$Ax^C\le N(x)\le Bx^C$$

Find the constant $C$

I tried to find the constant explicitly.

$$a_{1}=a_{0}(1+a^2_{0})=x(1+x^2) ;f_{1}(x)=x + x^3,\Longrightarrow f_{1}'(x)=3x^2+1>0$$
$$a_{1}=f_{1}(x)\in (0,2)$$
$$a_{2}=a_{1}(1+a^2_{1})=(x^3+x)(x^3+x+1)=t(t+2)\in (0,8),t=x^3+x$$
$$a_{n}=a_{n-1}(1+a^2_{n-1})\in (0,2^n(2^n+2))$$
Now I'm stuck

Background:This problem is a part of China middle school exam.

This problem seems very interesting to me. It is said that $C=2$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is yet another question by this user with no personal input, apart from some fake considerations doomed from the start (how are values of $a_n$ *greater* than $1$ even relevant to the problem, one wonders).

Comment: So ... $N(x) \equiv 1$ for all $x \geq .7$.

Comment: This problem is middle school problem,have simple methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a sequence $(b_n)$ by $b_0=1$ and $b_n=b_{n+1}+b_{n+1}^3$ for every $n\geqslant0$, then $(b_n)$ is decreasing to zero and, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$N(x)=n\iff x\in(b_n,b_{n-1}].$$ Furthermore, $$\frac1{b_{n}^2}-\frac1{b_{n-1}^2}=\frac1{b_{n}^2}\left(1-\frac1{(1+b_n^2)^2}\right)=\frac1{b_{n}^2}\left(1-(1-2b_n^2+o(b_n^2))\right)=2+o(1),$$ when $n\to\infty$, hence, summing these from $1$ to $n$, one gets $$2n\,b_n^2\to1.$$
Inverting this asymptotics for $b_n$ when $n\to\infty$ yields the asymptotics for $N(x)$ when $x\to0$ that $$2x^2\,N(x)\to1,$$ in particular, $$N(x)\in\Theta(x^C),\qquad\text{with}\quad C=-2.$$

Comment: Nice.But why $N(x)=n,\Longleftrightarrow x\in (b_{n},b_{n-1}]$, can you explain? Thank you

Comment: @math110 that can be proved by induction. The base is for 0.

Comment: Could you explain how $2n b_n^2 \to 1$ estimate was obtained from $\frac{1}{b_n^2}= O(2n) $? I mean, how does little o should be treated in case of the summation.